# How to create bas relief by using a normal face image

Tags: modeling, texture-baking

I am Mr.Wong , I would like to enquire if any of the experts can demonstrate a video of creating bas relief by using a normal face image? Any response will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, what do you call a normal face image?

Comment: Normal face image means photo taking by hand phone or camera only shot at head or face portion.

Comment: You can recreate a 3D face with softs like meshroom but you need several images. For a bas-relief it seems hard to recreate it from a simple picture, because it can't give any correct informations about the 3D relief of the face, for example if you convert it to b&w it won't be usable as a Bump map, but maybe someone has a trick to do it...

Comment: Thanks moonboots, I will keep study it .